# react-native run-android is failing after importing @react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

importing of google signin in react-native is throwing error in react-native run-android, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/android/app/src**/main/java/com/b/MainApplication.java:19: error: package co.apptailor.googlesignin does not exist
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;** 
                                ^
Note: /home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/android/app/src/debug/java/com/b/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s

```
at makeError (/home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/x/Documents/coding/y/z/a/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: are you on mac or windows?

Comment: @ZaidQureshi ubuntu

Comment: Hi there, we have encountered the same issue exactly. Wondering if you have found a solution?

Comment: @PhillipStack check there example folder

Comment: In our case, it turned out we had conflicting import packages. There was a deprecated package with the same package name in our package.json